# How can I save the instance state of this TextView in a fragment?

Tags: java, android-fragments, textview, android-savedstate

I have the text inputted by the user in an EditText replace the text of a TextView upon a button press. Once the TextView text has been changed, when I navigate to another fragment or activity and come back, the TextView has reverted back to its original text. I have tried multiple solutions to save the instance state to no avail.

Edit2: The is the latest code from the fragment

```
public class TeamFragment extends Fragment {

private TextView testTextView;
private EditText testEditText;
private SharedPreferences pref;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_team, container, false);


    Button button = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.recordBtn);
    testEditText = v.findViewById(R.id.testEditText);
    pref = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("my_pref",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = pref.edit();

    testTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.testTextView);
    final EditText testEditText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.testEditText);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            testTextView.setText(testEditText.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("val", testEditText.getText().toString());
            editor.apply();

        }
    });
    return v;

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    String val = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("my_pref",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("val", "n/a");
    if(val.equals("n/a")) {
        testTextView.setText(val);
    }

}

}
```

This is my layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/background_light"
android:padding="8dp">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Record"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tresEditText"
    android:id="@+id/recordBtn"
    android:onClick="displayEditText"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/testTextView"
    android:text="Test"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"/>
<EditText
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/testEditText"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: With this line in your xml android:onClick="displayEditText", you are telling your button to call a method named displayEditText(View view). But I see that you are also setting a click listener programmatically and tell your button to do something else. May be you forgot that line after refactoring?

Comment: I might've accidentally left that line in there when I was trying something else, I deleted it but the instance is still not being saved unfortunately.

Comment: Oh ok. That is because you are not setting the text you got from the preferences to your textview. Inside onStart callback, you set the text only if it has the default value "n/a". May be you wanted to make the opposite in fact?

Comment: Possibly? I would just like to change the textview text to match the text in the edittext when the user presses the record button and then remember that text the next time the user visits the page

Comment: Try to negate that if expression, like
 if(!val.equals("n/a")) {
        testTextView.setText(val);
    }

Comment: Great! You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Your app crashes because you have not initialized `EditText` and `TextView`.

Instead of overriding `onSaveInstanceState()`, consider using `SharedPreferences()` as `onSaveInstanceState()` is used to save the state when the device orientation is changed.
In your case, what you can do is to save textView data in `SharedPreference` and when you come back to the fragment, you can check in 'onStart()' whether the `SharedPreferences()` contain the saved value, then populate your textView accordingly.

You can do something like following:

```
public class TeamFragment extends Fragment {

private TextView testTextView;
private EditText testEditText;
private SharedPreferences pref;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable 
ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_team, container, false);

Button button = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.recordBtn);
textTextView = v.findViewById(R.id.your_id);
testEditText = v.findViewById(R.id.your_id);
pref = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("my_pref", 
Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
editor = pref.edit();

testTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.testTextView);
final EditText testEditText = (EditText) 
v.findViewById(R.id.testEditText);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        testTextView.setText(testEditText.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("val", testEditText.getText().toString());
        editor.apply();

    }
});
return v;

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    String val = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("my_pref", 
    Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("val", "n/a");
    if(val.equals("n/a")) {
      testTextView.setText(val);
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: I added that to my activity, but when I navigate to the fragment, the app still crashes, so I'm not sure what could be the issue.

Comment: I implemented your code, while the app doesnt crash, the textview does not save its instance. Is there someway I have to implement SharedPreferences in my MainActivtiy? Also, do I keep the onSaveInstanceState in my MainAcitivity? (I'm very new to java and Android Studio)

Comment: Shared preferences code works as I have tested but you might have some other issue, post your full class code

Comment: visit https://www.journaldev.com/9412/android-shared-preferences-example-tutorial

Comment: `onSaveInstanceState() is used to save the state when the device orientation is changed.` configuration changes ***and process death (low memory condition)***. But shared pref persists into an XML file, so technically files survives process restoration too.